# How to get for loop to move onto the next inner list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of zeros within a nested list. My code outputs 2 because it only goes through the first inner list.

This is what I have currently:

```
def e(xlst):
    cnt = 0
    for numbers in xlst:
        for numbers2 in numbers:
            if numbers2 == 0:
                cnt += 1
        return cnt
xlst = [[1,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]
e(xlst)
```

Comment: Your `return` is indented too far.

Answer (score 1):

You have misplaced the `return` , it should be matched with the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

The **return** statement is inside the first **for**, so after the first row it will return and exit the function

also, list has a built-in function **count**, that can be used to make the code a little simples and faster:

```
from time import time

def e(xlst):
    cnt = 0
    for numbers in xlst:
        for numbers2 in numbers:
            if numbers2 == 0:
                cnt += 1
    return cnt


def with_count(xlst):
    cnt = 0
    for numbers in xlst:
        cnt += numbers.count(0)
    return cnt

# Creates a 2D list with 300 rows of [1,0,0]
xlst = [[1,0,0]]*300

t0=time()
print(f'\nfirst function found: {e(xlst)}')
print(f'time: {time() - t0}\n')

t0=time()
print(f'second function found: {with_count(xlst)}')
print(f'time: {time() - t0}\n')
```

first function found: 600

time: 0.0003502368927001953

second function found: 600

time: 0.000194549560546875

Answer (score 0):

Correct the `return` indent

Code should be like this

```
def e(xlst):
    cnt = 0
    for numbers in xlst:
        for numbers2 in numbers:
            if numbers2 == 0:
                cnt += 1
    return cnt
xlst = [[1,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]
print(e(xlst))
```

It prints 3

Answer (score 0):

Using global variables is bad practice, but I am too tired to figure out how to do it without, without using two functions

```py
def e(xlst):
    cnt = 0
    if (type(xlst) == list):
        for x in xlst:
            e(x)
    elif (xlst == 0):
        cnt +=1
```

Here we use recursion, calling the function on each nested list. This works for infinitely nested lists.

Comment: You probably want to return something in your function.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it as a one liner.

```
from itertools import chain

def e(xlst):
    return len([i for i in chain.from_iterable(xlst) if i == 0])

xlst = [[1,0,0],[1,1,1],[1,1,0]]
print(e(xlst))
```

or without the temporary list.

```
def e(xlst):
    return sum(1 for i in chain.from_iterable(xlst) if i == 0)
```